# Подключение к MySQL

Tags: php

Всем здравствуйте. Помогите, подключаюсь к MySQL и пишет

> Не удалось подключиться к серверу MySql!

Хотя я создал БД. Вот код и пишет на 6 строчке ошибку?

```
<?php
$host   = 'localhost';
$user   = 'root';
$pass   = 'syn21';
$dbname = 'synape';
if (!mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass))
    die('Не удалось подключиться к серверу MySql!');
elseif (!mysql_select_db($dbname))
    die('Не удалось выбрать БД!');
?>
```

Comment: Да, на шестой.

Answer (score 1):

```
$db = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die('Не удалось подключиться к MySql!');
mysql_select_db($dbname, $db) or die('Не удалось выбрать БД!');
```

P.S. И не плохо бы выводить ошибку

```
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die('Облом!'.mysql_error());
```

Comment: Извините, но я не понял

Comment: Что именно не понятно? И покажите ошибку, которую выбивает при подключении, добавьте в свой запрос mysql_error()

Comment: Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in Z:\home\synape\www\connectdb.php on line 6
Не удалось подключиться к серверу MySql! вот ошибка

Comment: А вы на root ставили пароль? И если да, то правильно ли его в запросе написали?